# finding values not in a table with sql

Tags: sql

I have been given a list of OVER 500 users' emails to look up, in a table. Running a basic select statement:

```
select v_First_Name, v_middle_name, v_last_Name, v_user_email_id
from GTPDATA.USERS
WHERE UPPER(V_USER_EMAIL_ID) IN ('USER1@AON.COM', 'USER2@AON.COM');
```

I have noticed that I am returned only around 400 users. Could be due to email addresses spelled wrong. 
How do I get a list of users that are in the list I have been provided, but missing from the table?
Thanks

Comment: Dont they have an ID or something in common?

Comment: Execute a dual query with NOT IN. So you can analyze result set to understand better because those rows aren't extracted

Comment: I don't have their user id's so will have to go by their email addresses. These are also unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import your list into another SQL table NEWTABLE and then use

```
select 
   NEWTABLE.Email
  ,v_First_Name
  , v_middle_name
  , v_last_Name
  , v_user_email_id 
from GTPDATA.USERS 
RIGHT join NEWTABLE on UPPER(NEWTABLE.Email) = UPPER(V_USER_EMAIL_ID) 
WHERE V_USER_EMAIL_ID IS NULL
```

Comment: You're right, just edited it the second you commented :)

Comment: Overlapping comments - deleted my comment after you fixed the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your list of email addresses is in a table, right? Use a LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT list.* from list LEFT JOIN GTPDATA.USERS U on upper(V_USER_EMAIL_ID) = upper(list.email)
WHERE U.V_USER_EMAIL_ID IS NULL
```